# How to make a class JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization

How to make a Python class serializable?

```
class FileItem:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
```

Attempt to serialize to JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> x = FileItem('/foo/bar')
>>> json.dumps(x)
TypeError: Object of type 'FileItem' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that the answers all seem to answer the question "How do I serialize a class?" rather than the action question "How do I make a class serializable?" These answers assume that you're doing the serialization yourself, rather than passing the object along to some other module that serializes it.

Comment: If you're using Python3.5+, you could use jsons. It will convert your object (and ***all its attributes recursively***) to a dict.

```import jsons``` see answer below - it works perfectly fine

Comment: @KyleDelaney I was really hoping for an interface/magic method I could implement to become searializable too. I guess I will have to implement a `.to_dict()` function or something which can be called on the object before it is passed to the module which tries to serialize it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63718624/1497139 for a start for a JSONAble mixin

Comment: @FelixB. You can use the built-in `vars` function in combination with `json.dumps` (see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64469761/1587520)

Comment: @FelixB. If it suits your use case, you could use a dataclass, which has it's own `.__dict__`

Comment: It's amazing that in 11 years there has not been a single response that answers this question. OP states he wants to use `json.dumps` yet all the answers, including with the bounty awarded, involve creating a custom encoder, which dodges the point of the question entirely.

Comment: This article explains the specific methods of making a class serializable, which is exactly what the question asked: https://pynative.com/make-python-class-json-serializable/

Comment: @Mike a custom encoder is not required; a `default` hook - which is a simple parameter to `json.dumps` - suffices. One answer simply offers `json.dumps(..., default=vars)`. There's also an answer that does work solely by modifying the class: specifically, it must be modified to subtype `dict`. Your assessment of the answers is simply off base.

Comment: That said, this question serves as a canonical now, so it's entirely reasonable that it attracts answers that tell beginners the right thing(s) to do.

Comment: First [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848267/7437143) I found to make any arbitrary class and all of its children serialisable was given by @R H.

Comment: This article as @AsifShiraz points out, really helped to pick a method to my needs.
https://pynative.com/make-python-class-json-serializable/

Comment: The whole point of JSON is its *independence* from custom code. Don't entangle data with code! Instead, make your class know how to translate to/from a nested builtin python object (of type Builtin[Builtin] where Builtin = List|Tuple|Dict|float|str|bool).

Comment: learning python and coming from something like typescript, it's hard to believe how lousy python is with json... You should be able to serialize pretty much anything, especially a `dataclass`

Answer (score 719, accepted):

Do you have an idea about the expected output? For example, will this do?

```
>>> f  = FileItem("/foo/bar")
>>> magic(f)
'{"fname": "/foo/bar"}'
```

In that case you can merely call `json.dumps(f.__dict__)`.

If you want more customized output then you will have to subclass [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) and implement your own custom serialization.

For a trivial example, see below.

```
>>> from json import JSONEncoder
>>> class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            return o.__dict__    

>>> MyEncoder().encode(f)
'{"fname": "/foo/bar"}'
```

Then you pass this class into the [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps) method as `cls` kwarg:

```
json.dumps(cls=MyEncoder)
```

If you also want to decode then you'll have to supply a custom `object_hook` to the [`JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) class. For example:

```
>>> def from_json(json_object):
        if 'fname' in json_object:
            return FileItem(json_object['fname'])
>>> f = JSONDecoder(object_hook = from_json).decode('{"fname": "/foo/bar"}')
>>> f
<__main__.FileItem object at 0x9337fac>
>>>
```

Comment: Using `__dict__` will not work in all cases.  If the attributes have not been set after the object was instantiated, `__dict__` may not be fully populated.  In the example above, you're OK, but if you have class attributes that you also want to encode, those will not be listed in `__dict__` unless they have been modified in the class' `__init__` call or by some other way after the object was instantiated.

Comment: +1, but the `from_json()` function used as object-hook should have an `else: return json_object` statement, so it can deal with general objects as well.

Comment: @KrisHardy `__dict__` also doesn't work if you use `__slots__` on a new style class.

Comment: You could use a custom `JSONEncoder` as above to create a custom protocol, such as checking for the existence of `__json_serializable__` method and calling it to obtain a JSON serializable representation of the object. This would be in keeping with other Python patterns, like `__getitem__`, `__str__`, `__eq__`, and `__len__`.

Comment: am new to python...can we use these libraries (`json` or `simplejson`) to serialize/deserialize objects which are extensively used by python developers say pandas dataframe, series etc?

Comment: `__dict__` also won't work recursively, e.g., if an attribute of your object is another object.

Comment: `JSONEncoder` only call subclass's `default` method if the given data if non-standard.

Comment: @Mahesha999 use the df.to_json() method for Dataframe, Series, etc

Comment: As mentioned by @badp I ran into the problem of having used `__slots__` in for some of my classes, but I simply wrote a similar utility type function to serialize to json with 
`@property
    def as_json(self):
        return json.dumps({k:getattr(self, k) for k in self.__slots__ if type(getattr(self, k)) is not set})`

where in my case the filter clause of `is not set` is because sets are not json serializable. Otherwise though this works when you use `__slots__` and so don't have `__dict__` to iterate over. In my use case I don't need the sets, they are computed by the constructor

Comment: My comment above (apologizes for the formatting, can't really do a code block in a comment but this didn't seem worth another separate answer) doesn't address any concerns of recursion when class variables are themselves objects of other non-primitive classes. Just how to do the simple thing for simple class if you used `__slots__` and don't have `__dict__`. Almost everything I find here is going after the `__dict__` internal implementation of classes, but you don't have that if you predefine member variables with `__slots__`

Answer (score 858):

Here is a simple solution for a simple feature:

### `.toJSON()` Method

Instead of a JSON serializable class, implement a serializer method:

```py
import json

class Object:
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(
            self,
            default=lambda o: o.__dict__, 
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=4)
```

So you just call it to serialize:

```py
me = Object()
me.name = "Onur"
me.age = 35
me.dog = Object()
me.dog.name = "Apollo"

print(me.toJSON())
```

will output:

```json
{
    "age": 35,
    "dog": {
        "name": "Apollo"
    },
    "name": "Onur"
}
```

Comment: Very limited. If you have a dict {"foo":"bar","baz":"bat"}, that will serialize to JSON easily. If instead you have {"foo":"bar","baz":MyObject()}, then you cannot. The ideal situation would be that nested objects are serialized to JSON recursively, not explicitly.

Comment: It will still work. You're missing `o.__dict___`. Try your own example:  
`class MyObject(): def __init__(self): self.prop = 1
j = json.dumps({ "foo": "bar", "baz": MyObject() }, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)`

Comment: Is this solution reversible? I.e. Is it easy to reconstruct the object from json?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão No. You could have two different classes with the same fields. Objects a and b of that class (probably with the same properties) would have the same `a.__dict__` / `b.__dict__`.

Comment: However, you could probably add a field `unjson_class` or so which gives a hint which class the object originally had. Then you could use introspection of your module and use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2169191/562769 to get the object back.

Comment: This does not work with `datetime.datetime` instances. It throws the following error: `'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: The following will work for anything that doesn't have a `__dict__`: `def _try(o):
    try:
        return o.__dict__
    except:
        return str(o)` and `def to_JSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: _try(o), sort_keys=True, indent=0, separators=(',',':')).replace('\n', '')`

Comment: @J.C.Leitão yes, it is reversible.  when you load the json you can add each key/value pair to the object __dict__ property see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object

Comment: I must be missing something but that seems like it doesn't work (ie., `json.dumps(me)` doesn't call `Object`'s `toJSON` method.

Comment: You can use `default=vars` instead of `default=lambda o: o.__dict__`.

Comment: @cglacet That is because he didn't make the class serializable, he just made a method that spits JSON String. This is not a proper answer for the question, it is more of a hack for special cases. But the correct one is above. If you would need YourObject getting serialized as a part/content of another ParentObject, you need to create an encoder.

Comment: The question specifically asks about making json.dumps(). Not how to implement all of JSON serialization yourself.

Comment: 744 people did not understand the question

Comment: I found this to be super useful for finding out what classes don't work (or just bypassing them).  This assumes, of course, you don't care about missing some data.
    def default_serialize_func(o):
        if hasattr(o, '__dict__'):
            return o.__dict__
        return f"<could not serialize {o.__class__}>"

Comment: Wow, comments are supremely broken in formatting ability.  Check out this gist for your eyes to stop bleeding:

https://gist.github.com/terabyte/8b961c29eab7fd155ddbe115d7941326

Comment: I may be late but to serialize a `datetime` with classes in classes: `json.dumps(myObject, default=lambda o: o.isoformat() if (isinstance(o, datetime.datetime)) else o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)` - Do not need to implement an additional function.

Comment: Is there a way to make this callable for lists?

Comment: @OnurYıldırım I reiterate NdrsImpk's question. Is there a way to make it callable for a list of object, because with this, the only way to call it a list of object is to loop on it. This way it creates multiple json for each Object, but I would like one for all the Object (The list of Object)

Comment: What is the point of this answer when it doesn't include the reverse operation?

Answer (score 263):

For more complex classes you could consider the tool [**jsonpickle**](http://jsonpickle.github.io/):

> jsonpickle is a Python library for serialization and deserialization of complex Python objects to and from JSON.
>
> The standard Python libraries for encoding Python into JSON, such as the stdlib’s json, simplejson, and demjson, can only handle Python primitives that have a direct JSON equivalent (e.g. dicts, lists, strings, ints, etc.). jsonpickle builds on top of these libraries and allows more complex data structures to be serialized to JSON. jsonpickle is highly configurable and extendable–allowing the user to choose the JSON backend and add additional backends.

Transform an object into a JSON string:

```
import jsonpickle
json_string = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
```

Recreate a Python object from a JSON string:

```
recreated_obj = jsonpickle.decode(json_string)
```

*[(link to jsonpickle on PyPi)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpickle/)*

Comment: Coming from C#, this is what I was expecting. A simple one liner and no messing with the classes.

Comment: jsonpickle is awesome. It worked perfectly for a huge, complex, messy object with many levels of classes

Comment: is there an example of the proper way to save this to a file? The documentation only shows how to encode and decode a `jsonpickle` object. Also, this was not able to decode a dict of dicts containing pandas dataframes.

Comment: @user5359531 you can use `obj = jsonpickle.decode(file.read())` and `file.write(jsonpickle.encode(obj))`.

Comment: It works for me!. It is what I needed. I just wanted to print a behave scenario object.

Comment: This is a great solution.  Rather than building a complex JSON decoder extension for the json module, I was able to serialize my class with one line: s=jsonpickle.encode(self).  Restoration was every bit as simple. This is the true Python spirit. +1

Comment: Sadly, doesn't seem to work on a openpyxl spreadsheet. I'm trying to turn a spreadsheet into .json, write it to a file, which works great. Then read that .json file back in, decode and save back to Excel. Unfortunately it fails on decode with `Cannot convert [] to Excel`.

Comment: Just have to be careful that you don't expose yourself to RCE if deserializing data from untrusted sources

Comment: As a side note, if using redis to stream, replace `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` with `jsonpickle.encode()` and `jsonpickle.decode()`.  You will save having to write tons of boiler-plate code!

Comment: Despite being useful, this is still a link-only answer.

Comment: @Jerther Coming from python, we aren't all that different. This solution does not require modification of the class-to-be-serialized, it is simple and it's naming conventions are good enough to self document what's going on. That's the correct answer IMO.

Comment: I've had jsonpickle fail with decoding dataframes, crashing the kernel in jupyter. as it was a dataframe in a class, i therefore had to use this workaround in order to serialize the class https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle/issues/213

Comment: @johnjps111 That is likely because the JSON decoder cannot tell between `[]` an empty spreadsheet object and `[]` an empty list. Not totally sure on that, but it would be my suspicion

Comment: Is there a reason why one would **not** want to use this as a solution in all cases? To me, this looks like a *canonical, default, no-brainer, no-thinking required solution*. In other words, something people should "just use" without further consideration. However, I am wondering if there might be a reason why you would not want to "just use this".

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant it is inherently unsafe. Same as just `pickle` lib. If there is some Python code embedded in the JSON that's being decoded - it will be executed. That's the #1 thing to consider when picking this over custom decoders for `json`

Comment: @MickeyDickey Right ok thanks that does make a lot of sense. Since reading these questions I sort of convinced myself that `jsons` might be the "no brainer" solution. (Maybe with some configuration options to remove private fields.)

Answer (score 218):

Most of the answers involve changing the call to **json.dumps()**, which is not always possible or desirable (it may happen inside a framework component for example).

If you want to be able to call  **json.dumps(obj)** as is, then a simple solution is inheriting from **dict**:

```
class FileItem(dict):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        dict.__init__(self, fname=fname)

f = FileItem('tasks.txt')
json.dumps(f)  #No need to change anything here
```

This works if your class is just basic data representation, for trickier things you can always set keys explicitly in the call to `dict.__init__()`.

This works because `json.dumps()` checks if the object is one of several known types via a rather unpythonic `isinstance(value, dict)` - so it would be possible to fudge this with `__class__` and some other methods if you really don't want to inherit from `dict`.

Comment: This can really be a nice solution :) I believe for my case it is. Benefits: you communicate the "shape" of the object by making it a class with init, it is inherently serializable and it looks interpretable as __repr__.

Comment: Though "dot-access" is still missing :(

Comment: Ahh that seems to work! Thanks, not sure why this is not the accepted answer. I totally agree that changing the `dumps` is not a good solution. 

By the way, in most cases you probably want to have `dict` inheritance together with delegation, which means that you will have some `dict` type attribute inside your class, you will then pass this attribute as parameter as initialisation something like `super().__init__(self.elements)`.

Comment: In my use case I needed to store data that was "invisible" to json.dumps(), so I used this method.  The class DictWithRider takes in an arbitrary object, stores it as a member, and makes it accessible via a function get_rider_obj() but does not pass it to dict.__init__().  So parts of the application who want to see the "hidden" data can call d.get_rider_obj() but json.dumps() sees basically an empty dict.  As @PascalVKooten mentioned, you can't access regular members with dot notation, but you can access functions.

Comment: for simple use this is ideal. dot notation can be easily enabled by additional lines subsequent to ```dict.__init__(``` line as ```self.fname = fname``` and the object can be deserialised with ```f = FileItem(**json.loads(serialised_f))```

Comment: I absolutely love this one for its simplicity. You have to design your classes completely (no monkey-patching), but it works really nicely, even if your class members are lists of objects.

Comment: for "dot-access" I recommend using properties instead of adding additional attributes

Comment: this solution's a bit hacky - for a true, production quality solution, replace json.dumps() and json.loads() with jsonpickle.encode() and jsonpickle.decode(). You will avoid having to write ugly boilerplate code, and most importantly, if you are able to pickle the object, you should be able to serialize it with jsonpickle without boilerplate code (complex containers/objects will just work).

Comment: @kfmfe04 this answer addresses cases where you have no control over the code which calls `json.dumps`.

Comment: It would be nice to explain _why_ this works, though. What Python magic is being relied upon here, and can we just implement that directly by implementing a special dunder function?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans there's no magic here, Python or otherwise, we're just subclassing `dict`. That works because `json.dumps` uses `JSONEncoder` which does a rather unpythonic `isinstance(value, dict)` - so unfortunately merely implementing the required methods won't work here.

Comment: That is literally the magic I was hoping to get explained. It would be quite useful to put the bit about it using isinstance, explicitly checking for instances of `dict`, in the post =) That said, there _is_ some magic pertaining to the json `default` function, which you can override as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469473/740553 and actually works really well. (why this is not the default json encoder behaviour is a bit of a mystery, as "objects" in json are just the data aspect, so literally just the dict of instance values)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans A function in a library checking the type of an object is neither magic, python specific or pythonic. If there was python "magic" at play we probably wouldn't need this hack. Happy to update the answer to include the additional explanation however.

Comment: Another alternative, which is perhaps better from an OOP / design perspective is rather than to inherit from a `dict` (because you probably are not really building a `dict`) instead use composition, and have the class wrap a single `dict` object. In other words, contain a single `dict`. Serialization and deserialization require two functions to serialize and deserialize the inner `dict`.

Comment: Some may consider that this comes with it's own disadvantage. You will have to write get/set methods for each keyed value of the dict you want to expose get/set operations for. If your dict contains N keys, that's 2 N functions to maintain.

Comment: surprise: [collections.UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict) is not JSON serializable, also `collections.UserList` and `collections.UserString`

Answer (score 194):

As mentioned in many other answers you can pass a function to `json.dumps` to convert objects that are not one of the types supported by default to a supported type. Surprisingly none of them mentions the simplest case, which is to use the built-in function [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to convert objects into a dict containing all their attributes:

```
json.dumps(obj, default=vars)
```

Note that this covers only basic cases, if you need more specific serialization for certain types (e.g. exluding certain attributes or for objects that don't have a `__dict__` attribute) you need to use a custom function or a `JSONEncoder` as desribed in the other answers.

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by `default=vars`, does that mean that `vars` is the default serializer? If not: This does not really solve the case where you can not influence how `json.dumps` is called. If you simply pass an object to a library and that library calls `json.dumps` on that object, it doesn't really help that you have implemented `vars` if that library does not use `dumps` this way. In that sense it is equivalent to a custom `JSONEncoder`.

Comment: You are correct, it is nothing else than just a simple choice for a custom serializer and doesn't solve the case you describe. If I see it correctly there is no solution to the case were you don't control how `json.dumps` is invoked.

Comment: For some objects, this approach will throw `vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`

Comment: Thanks for this, pretty straightforward to use with library that have proper definition built in.

Comment: Any workaround for the error `vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`?

Comment: this does not work: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Answer (score 103):

Just add `to_json` method to your class like this:

```
def to_json(self):
  return self.message # or how you want it to be serialized
```

And add this code *(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18561055))*, to somewhere at the top of everything:

```
from json import JSONEncoder

def _default(self, obj):
    return getattr(obj.__class__, "to_json", _default.default)(obj)

_default.default = JSONEncoder().default
JSONEncoder.default = _default
```

This will monkey-patch json module when it's imported, so
`JSONEncoder.default()` automatically checks for a special `to_json()`
method and uses it to encode the object if found.

[Just like Onur said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538391/4575793), but this time you don't have to update every `json.dumps()` in your project.

Comment: Big thanks! This is the only answer that allows me to do what I want: be able to serialize an object without changing the existing code. The other methods mostly do not work for me. The object is defined in a third-party library, and the serialization code is third-party too. Changing them will be awkward. With your method, I only need to do `TheObject.to_json = my_serializer`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.
I did a small variation:


```import json

_fallback = json._default_encoder.default
json._default_encoder.default = lambda obj: getattr(obj.__class__,  "to_json", _fallback)(obj)
```

Comment: There's gotta be a better way than hacking the JSON encoder at the top of everything. Too brittle to be a reliable solution

Answer (score 83):

#### TLDR: copy-paste Option 1 or Option 2 below

## A Full Answer to: 
Making Pythons `json` module work with Your Class

AKA, solving: `json.dumps({ "thing": YOUR_CLASS() })`

##### Explanation:

- Yes, a reliable solution exists
- No, there is no python "official" solution

  - By official solution, I mean there is no way (as of 2024) to add a method to your class (like `toJSON` in JavaScript) and/or no way to register your class with the built-in json module. When something like `json.dumps([1,2, your_obj])` is executed, python doesn't check a lookup table or object method.
  - I'm not sure why other answers don't explain this
  - The closest official approach is probably [andyhasit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207881/4367134) which is to inherit from a dictionary. However, inheriting from a dictionary doesn't work very well for many custom classes like AdvancedDateTime, or pytorch tensors.
- The ideal workaround is this:

  - Add `def __json__(self)` method to your class
  - Mutate `json.dumps` to check for `__json__` method (affects everywhere, even pip modules that import json)
  - *Note:* Modifing builtin stuff usually isn't great, however this change should have no side effects, even if its applied multiple times by different codebases. It is entirely reversable durning runtime (if a module wants to undo the modification). And for better or worse, is the best that can done at the moment.

#### Option 1: Let [a Module](https://github.com/jeff-hykin/json_fix.git) do the Patching

`pip install json-fix` 
(extended + packaged version of [Fancy John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764817/4367134), thank you @FancyJohn)

`your_class_definition.py`

```py
import json_fix

class YOUR_CLASS:
    def __json__(self):
        # YOUR CUSTOM CODE HERE
        #    you probably just want to do:
        #        return self.__dict__
        return "a built-in object that is naturally json-able"
```

Thats it.

Example usage:

```
from your_class_definition import YOUR_CLASS
import json

json.dumps([1,2, YOUR_CLASS()], indent=0)
# '[\n1,\n2,\n"a built-in object that is naturally json-able"\n]'
```

To make `json.dumps` work for Numpy arrays, Pandas DataFrames, and other 3rd party objects, see [the Module](https://github.com/jeff-hykin/json_fix.git) (only ~2 lines of code but needs explanation).

#### How does it work? Well...

#### Option 2: Patch json.dumps yourself

**Note**: this approach is simplified, it fails on known edgecases (ex: if your custom class inherits from `dict` or another builtin), and it misses out on controlling the json behavior for external classes (numpy arrays, datetime, dataframes, tensors, etc).

some_file_thats_imported_before_your_class_definitions.py

```py
# Step: 1
# create the patch
from json import JSONEncoder
def wrapped_default(self, obj):
    return getattr(obj.__class__, "__json__", wrapped_default.default)(obj)
wrapped_default.default = JSONEncoder().default
   
# apply the patch
JSONEncoder.original_default = JSONEncoder.default
JSONEncoder.default = wrapped_default
```

your_class_definition.py

```py
# Step 2
class YOUR_CLASS:
    def __json__(self, **options):
        # YOUR CUSTOM CODE HERE
        #    you probably just want to do:
        #        return self.__dict__
        return "a built-in object that is natually json-able"
```

_

#### All other answers seem to be "Best practices/approaches to serializing a custom object"

Which, is alreadly covered [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=jsonencoder#json.JSONEncoder) (search "complex" for an example of encoding complex numbers)

Comment: It's a bit aggressive to modify `json.dumps` across the whole codebase, but this is clearly the nicest solution IMO.

Comment: Good solution. is there an equivalent for json.loads?

Comment: Sadly no @Sam and there kind of fundamentally can't be; json-dumping is effectively a one-way operation. Ex: think of a BigInt class that converts itself to a string for json.dumps. Now consider a random string-value somewhere in a json file. Maybe that string-value contains all-digits, does that mean it should be loaded as a BigInt? What about strings that just coincidentally contain all-digits, but are supposed to remain as strings? There's no way that json.loads can know, so instead you have to do something like `BigInt.from_json(a_str)` with a string that you KNOW is should be a BigInt.

Comment: really, I'm new to python, but man, simple things like serialize/deserialize classes to JSON should be *simple*. So many answers and really no solution. 
why do people like python so much these days? I wonder how many successful production software are created with python.
It's just a pain for every little things. I come from dotnet/javascript world.

Comment: @JeffHykin That's where type information comes in. Surely the solution would be to use class methods or a class constructor. This provides type information to disambiguate the type.

Answer (score 68):

I like [Onur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538391/44330) but would expand to include an optional `toJSON()` method for objects to serialize themselves:

```
def dumper(obj):
    try:
        return obj.toJSON()
    except:
        return obj.__dict__
print json.dumps(some_big_object, default=dumper, indent=2)
```

Comment: I found this to be the best balance between using the existing `json.dumps` and introducing custom handling. Thanks!

Comment: I actually really like this; but rather than `try-catch` would probably do something like `if 'toJSON' in obj.__attrs__():`... to avoid a silent failure (in the event of failure in toJSON() for some other reason than it not being there)... a failure which potentially leads to data corruption.

Comment: @thclark as I understand it, idomatic python asks for forgiveness, not permission, so try-except is the right approach, but the correct exception should be caught, an AttributeError in this case.

Comment: @phil a few years older and wiser now, I'd agree with you.

Comment: This really should be catching an `AttributeError` explicitly

Comment: And what if `AttributeError` is raised inside `obj.toJSON()`?

Answer (score 48):

If you're using Python3.5+, you could use [`jsons`](https://jsons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest). (PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/jsons/) It will convert your object (and all its attributes recursively) to a dict.

```
import jsons

a_dict = jsons.dump(your_object)
```

Or if you wanted a string:

```
a_str = jsons.dumps(your_object)
```

Or if your class implemented `jsons.JsonSerializable`:

```
a_dict = your_object.json
```

Comment: If you are able to use Python 3.7+, I found that the cleanest solution to convert python classes to dicts and JSON strings (and viceversa) is to mix the `jsons` library with [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html). So far, so good for me!

Comment: This is an external library, not built into the standard Python install.

Comment: only for class that has __slots__ attribute

Comment: You can, but you don't need to use __slots__. Only when dumping according to the signature of a specific class you'll need __slots__. In the upcoming version 1.1.0 that is also no longer the case.

Comment: This library is extremely slow in both deserialization/serialization, at least from personal testing. I'd suggest other ser libraries instead.

Comment: How are you charting the JSON in the visuals/images? 

By the way this works. `json.dumps(obj)` then `json.loads(obj)`.

Comment: One still-missing feature is an option for human consumption / readability. Pretty-printing / indenting is not yet implemented (at least not yet as of v1.6.1).

Answer (score 44):

Another option is to wrap JSON dumping in its own class:

```
import json

class FileItem:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

Or, even better, subclassing FileItem class from a `JsonSerializable` class:

```
import json

class JsonSerializable(object):
    def toJson(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.toJson()


class FileItem(JsonSerializable):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
```

Testing:

```
>>> f = FileItem('/foo/bar')
>>> f.toJson()
'{"fname": "/foo/bar"}'
>>> f
'{"fname": "/foo/bar"}'
>>> str(f) # string coercion
'{"fname": "/foo/bar"}'
```

Comment: Hi, 

I don't really like this "custom encoder" approach, it would be better if u can make your class json seriazable. I try, and try and try and nothing. Is there any idea how to do this. The thing is that json module test your class against built in python types, and even says for custom classes make your encoder :). 
Can it be faked? So I could do something to my class so it behave like simple list to json module? I try __subclasscheck__ and __instancecheck__ but nothing.

Comment: @ADRENALIN You could inherit from a primary type (probably dict), if all class attribute values are serializable and you don't mind hacks. You could also use jsonpickle or json_tricks or something instead of the standard one (still a custom encoder, but not one you need to write or call). The former pickles the instance, the latter stores it as dict of attributes, which you can change by implementing `__json__encode__` / `__json_decode__` (disclosure: I made the last one).

Comment: That doesn't make the object serializeable for the json class. It only provides a method to get a json string returned (trivial). Thus `json.dumps(f)` will fail. That's not what's been asked.

Comment: I don't see the point of this. You just created a class `JsonSerializable` which you are using as an interface to provide default implementations of `toJson` ?

Answer (score 35):

I came across this problem the other day and implemented a more general version of an Encoder for Python objects that can **handle nested objects** and **inherited fields**:

```py
import json
import inspect

class ObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, "to_json"):
            return self.default(obj.to_json())
        elif hasattr(obj, "__dict__"):
            d = dict(
                (key, value)
                for key, value in inspect.getmembers(obj)
                if not key.startswith("__")
                and not inspect.isabstract(value)
                and not inspect.isbuiltin(value)
                and not inspect.isfunction(value)
                and not inspect.isgenerator(value)
                and not inspect.isgeneratorfunction(value)
                and not inspect.ismethod(value)
                and not inspect.ismethoddescriptor(value)
                and not inspect.isroutine(value)
            )
            return self.default(d)
        return obj
```

Example:

```py
class C(object):
    c = "NO"
    def to_json(self):
        return {"c": "YES"}

class B(object):
    b = "B"
    i = "I"
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        
    def f(self):
        print "f"

class A(B):
    a = "A"
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = [{"ab": B("y")}]
        self.c = C()

print json.dumps(A(), cls=ObjectEncoder, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

Result:

```json
{
  "a": "A", 
  "b": [
    {
      "ab": {
        "b": "B", 
        "i": "I", 
        "y": "y"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "c": {
    "c": "YES"
  }, 
  "i": "I"
}
```

Comment: Although this is a bit old..I'm facing some circular imports error. So instead of `return obj` in the last line I did this `return super(ObjectEncoder, self).default(obj)`. Reference [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249115/serializing-output-to-json-valueerror-circular-reference-detected)

Answer (score 17):

**A really simplistic one-liner solution**

```py
import json

json.dumps(your_object, default=vars)
```

**The end!**

What comes below is a test.

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Company:
    id: int
    name: str

@dataclass
class User:
    id: int
    name: str
    email: str
    company: Company


company = Company(id=1, name="Example Ltd")
user = User(id=1, name="John Doe", email="john@doe.net", company=company)


json.dumps(user, default=vars)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "id": 1, 
  "name": "John Doe", 
  "email": "john@doe.net", 
  "company": {
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Example Ltd"
  }
}
```

Comment: I worked for me! In my opinion, it is the best solution so far.

Comment: This is by far the best solution.

Comment: Nice clean one-liner \o/

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: `default=lambda __o: __o.__dict__` can be replaced by `default=vars`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64469761). Also see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars).

Answer (score 15):

```
import simplejson

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mail):
        self.name = name
        self.mail = mail

    def _asdict(self):
        return self.__dict__

print(simplejson.dumps(User('alice', 'alice@mail.com')))
```

if using standard `json`, you need to define a `default` function

```
import json
def default(o):
    return o._asdict()

print(json.dumps(User('alice', 'alice@mail.com'), default=default))
```

Comment: I simplifed this by removing the _asdict function with a lambda

```json.dumps(User('alice', 'alice@mail.com'), default=lambda x: x.__dict__)```

Answer (score 8):

`json` is limited in terms of objects it can print, and `jsonpickle` (you may need a `pip install jsonpickle`) is limited in terms it can't indent text. If you would like to inspect the contents of an object whose class you can't change, I still couldn't find a straighter way than:

```
 import json
 import jsonpickle
 ...
 print  json.dumps(json.loads(jsonpickle.encode(object)), indent=2)
```

Note: that still they can't print the object methods.

Answer (score 7):

The most simple answer

```
class Object(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

# test
obj = Object()
obj.name = "John"
obj.age = 25
obj.brothers = [ Object() ]
text = json.dumps(obj)
```

Now it gives you the output, don't change anything to json.dumps(...)

```
'{"name": "John", "age": 25, "brothers": [{}]}'
```

Comment: Step by step:
1. Make sure your object inherits `dict`.
2. Add the `__getattr__`, so that json.dumps can access your attributes.
3. Add the `__setattr__`, so that when you add your own props, they are added to the dictionary.

Comment: This is a nice answer if you really can't change `json.dumps` by injecting a custom serializer.

Comment: Best answer so far, unless someone find an annotation to avoid having to repeat the above to all classes, or creating a base class with those 2 methods?

If you want to avoid inheriting from `dict`, you can use `self.__dict__[key]`

Answer (score 6):

To throw another log on this 11 year old fire, I want a solution that meets the following criteria:

- Allows an instance of class FileItem to be serialized using only `json.dumps(obj)`
- Allows FileItem instances to have properties: fileItem.fname
- Allows FileItem instances to be given to any library which will serialise it using `json.dumps(obj)`
- Doesn't require any other fields to be passed to `json.dumps` (like a custom serializer)

IE:

```
fileItem = FileItem('filename.ext')
assert json.dumps(fileItem) == '{"fname": "filename.ext"}'
assert fileItem.fname == 'filename.ext'
```

My solution is:

- Have obj's class inherit from `dict`
- Map each object property to the underlying `dict`

```
class FileItem(dict):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self['fname'] = fname

    #fname property
    fname: str = property()
    @fname.getter
    def fname(self):
        return self['fname']

    @fname.setter
    def fname(self, value: str):
        self['fname'] = value

    #Repeat for other properties
```

Yes, this is somewhat long winded if you have lots of properties, but it is JSONSerializable and it behaves like an object and you can give it to any library  that's going to `json.dumps(obj)` it.

Comment: Just an FYI, the type of `fname` isn’t `str` just because it’s a property that evaluates to a `str` at runtime. if you need to annotate `fname` as you have shown it should likely be something like `fname: property = property()`; the type of the getter and setter methods is `typing.MethodWrapperType` – and you can annotate `fname.getter(…)` to show a `str` return type.

Comment: Inheriting from dict works. I then added `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods on my class so that it will use the dict values for any undefined attributes.

Comment: I don't understand the line `fname: str = property()`. Isn't this acting like a static variable? (Not sure what Python calls them - a non member variable in other OO languages.)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my 3 cents ...
This demonstrates explicit json serialization for a tree-like python object.
Note: If you actually wanted some code like this you could use the [twisted 
FilePath](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.filepath.FilePath.html) class.

```
import json, sys, os

class File:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def isdir(self):
        return os.path.isdir(self.path)

    def isfile(self):
        return os.path.isfile(self.path)

    def children(self):        
        return [File(os.path.join(self.path, f)) 
                for f in os.listdir(self.path)]

    def getsize(self):        
        return os.path.getsize(self.path)

    def getModificationTime(self):
        return os.path.getmtime(self.path)

def _default(o):
    d = {}
    d['path'] = o.path
    d['isFile'] = o.isfile()
    d['isDir'] = o.isdir()
    d['mtime'] = int(o.getModificationTime())
    d['size'] = o.getsize() if o.isfile() else 0
    if o.isdir(): d['children'] = o.children()
    return d

folder = os.path.abspath('.')
json.dump(File(folder), sys.stdout, default=_default)
```

Answer (score 5):

This class can do the trick, it converts object to standard json .

```
import json


class Serializer(object):
    @staticmethod
    def serialize(object):
        return json.dumps(object, default=lambda o: o.__dict__.values()[0])
```

usage:

```
Serializer.serialize(my_object)
```

working in `python2.7` and `python3`.

Comment: I liked this method the most. I ran into issues when trying to serialize more complex objects whos members/methods aren't serializable. Here's my implementation that works on more objects:

```
class Serializer(object):
    @staticmethod
    def serialize(obj):
        def check(o):
            for k, v in o.__dict__.items():
                try:
                    _ = json.dumps(v)
                    o.__dict__[k] = v
                except TypeError:
                    o.__dict__[k] = str(v)
            return o
        return json.dumps(check(obj).__dict__, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 5):

[jaraco](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/issues/52#issuecomment-23667961) gave a pretty neat answer. I needed to fix some minor things, but this works:

### Code

```
# Your custom class
class MyCustom(object):
    def __json__(self):
        return {
            'a': self.a,
            'b': self.b,
            '__python__': 'mymodule.submodule:MyCustom.from_json',
        }

    to_json = __json__  # supported by simplejson

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json):
        obj = cls()
        obj.a = json['a']
        obj.b = json['b']
        return obj

# Dumping and loading
import simplejson

obj = MyCustom()
obj.a = 3
obj.b = 4

json = simplejson.dumps(obj, for_json=True)

# Two-step loading
obj2_dict = simplejson.loads(json)
obj2 = MyCustom.from_json(obj2_dict)

# Make sure we have the correct thing
assert isinstance(obj2, MyCustom)
assert obj2.__dict__ == obj.__dict__
```

Note that we need two steps for loading. For now, the `__python__` property
is not used.

### How common is this?

Using the method of [AlJohri](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/issues/52#issuecomment-261795387), I check popularity of approaches:

Serialization (Python -> JSON):

- [`to_json`](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=to_json&type=Code): 266,595 on 2018-06-27
- [`toJSON`](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=toJSON&type=Code): 96,307 on 2018-06-27
- [`__json__`](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=__json__&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93): 8,504 on 2018-06-27
- [`for_json`](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=for_json&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93): 6,937 on 2018-06-27

Deserialization (JSON -> Python):

- [`from_json`](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=from_json&type=Code): 226,101 on 2018-06-27

Comment: You should delete the parts where you search github for strings. This seems to be a bit pointless because if you inspect the results you can see it doesn't give the statistics you want to present anyway. Also it distracts from what it otherwise a pretty good answer. I personally like the class method approach for deserialization because it enables you to use type information to tell Python what type you want to end up with. (Inspecting a string it can't know that. A string could represent any type, given a weird enough encoding, in theory. It is ambiguous.)

Answer (score 4):

```
import json

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'baz'
        self._qux = 'flub'

    def somemethod(self):
        pass

'''
The parameter default(obj) is a function that should return a 
serializable version of obj or raise TypeError. The default 
default simply raises TypeError. 

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.dumps
'''
def default(instance):
    return {k: v
            for k, v in vars(instance).items()
            if not str(k).startswith('_')}

json_foo = json.dumps(Foo(), default=default)
assert '{"bar": "baz"}' == json_foo

print(json_foo)
```

Comment: From [doc](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.dumps): The parameter ``default(obj)`` is a function that should return a serializable version
    of obj or raise TypeError.    
The default ``default`` simply raises TypeError.

Comment: @luckydonald isn't that what this does? A new `default` function is declared that returns a dictionary, and everything works as expected.

Comment: _@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans_ yes. I just added the documentation, as only code as above isn't really helpful in explaining it.

Answer (score 4):

This has worked well for me:

```
class JsonSerializable(object):

    def serialize(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.serialize()

    @staticmethod
    def dumper(obj):
        if "serialize" in dir(obj):
            return obj.serialize()

        return obj.__dict__
```

and then

```
class FileItem(JsonSerializable):
    ...
```

and

```
log.debug(json.dumps(<my object>, default=JsonSerializable.dumper, indent=2))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind installing a package for it, you can use [json-tricks](https://json-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
pip install json-tricks
```

After that you just need to import `dump(s)` from `json_tricks` instead of json, and it'll usually work:

```
from json_tricks import dumps
json_str = dumps(cls_instance, indent=4)
```

which'll give

```
{
        "__instance_type__": [
                "module_name.test_class",
                "MyTestCls"
        ],
        "attributes": {
                "attr": "val",
                "dct_attr": {
                        "hello": 42
                }
        }
}
```

And that's basically it!

---

This will work great in general. There are some exceptions, e.g. if special things happen in `__new__`, or more metaclass magic is going on.

Obviously loading also works (otherwise what's the point):

```
from json_tricks import loads
json_str = loads(json_str)
```

This does assume that `module_name.test_class.MyTestCls` can be imported and hasn't changed in non-compatible ways. **You'll get back an instance**, not some dictionary or something, and it should be an identical copy to the one you dumped.

If you want to customize how something gets (de)serialized, you can add special methods to your class, like so:

```
class CustomEncodeCls:
        def __init__(self):
                self.relevant = 42
                self.irrelevant = 37

        def __json_encode__(self):
                # should return primitive, serializable types like dict, list, int, string, float...
                return {'relevant': self.relevant}

        def __json_decode__(self, **attrs):
                # should initialize all properties; note that __init__ is not called implicitly
                self.relevant = attrs['relevant']
                self.irrelevant = 12
```

which serializes only part of the attributes parameters, as an example.

And as a free bonus, you get (de)serialization of numpy arrays, date & times, ordered maps, as well as the ability to include comments in json.

Disclaimer: I created [json_tricks](https://github.com/mverleg/pyjson_tricks), because I had the same problem as you.

Comment: I've just tested json_tricks and it worked beautify (in 2019).

Comment: Why doesn't this answer have more upvotes? It looks like a de-facto default solution. Are there any downsides to this approach? What makes this library different from `jsons` and `jsonpickle` ?

Answer (score 3):

[Kyle Delaney's comment is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2122672/kyle-delaney) so i tried to use the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538391/1497139 as well as an improved version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10254820/1497139

to create a "JSONAble" mixin.

So to make a class JSON serializeable use "JSONAble" as a super class and either call:

```
 instance.toJSON()
```

or

```
 instance.asJSON()
```

for the two offered methods. You could also extend the JSONAble class with other approaches offered here.

The test example for the Unit Test with Family and Person sample results in:

**toJSOn():**

```
{
    "members": {
        "Flintstone,Fred": {
            "firstName": "Fred",
            "lastName": "Flintstone"
        },
        "Flintstone,Wilma": {
            "firstName": "Wilma",
            "lastName": "Flintstone"
        }
    },
    "name": "The Flintstones"
}
```

**asJSOn():**

```
{'name': 'The Flintstones', 'members': {'Flintstone,Fred': {'firstName': 'Fred', 'lastName': 'Flintstone'}, 'Flintstone,Wilma': {'firstName': 'Wilma', 'lastName': 'Flintstone'}}}
```

**Unit Test with Family and Person sample**

```
def testJsonAble(self):
        family=Family("The Flintstones")
        family.add(Person("Fred","Flintstone")) 
        family.add(Person("Wilma","Flintstone"))
        json1=family.toJSON()
        json2=family.asJSON()
        print(json1)
        print(json2)

class Family(JSONAble):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.members={}
    
    def add(self,person):
        self.members[person.lastName+","+person.firstName]=person

class Person(JSONAble):
    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName):
        self.firstName=firstName;
        self.lastName=lastName;
```

**jsonable.py defining JSONAble mixin**

```
 '''
Created on 2020-09-03

@author: wf
'''
import json

class JSONAble(object):
    '''
    mixin to allow classes to be JSON serializable see
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
    
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, 
            sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        
    def getValue(self,v):
        if (hasattr(v, "asJSON")):
            return v.asJSON()
        elif type(v) is dict:
            return self.reprDict(v)
        elif type(v) is list:
            vlist=[]
            for vitem in v:
                vlist.append(self.getValue(vitem))
            return vlist
        else:   
            return v
    
    def reprDict(self,srcDict):
        '''
        get my dict elements
        '''
        d = dict()
        for a, v in srcDict.items():
            d[a]=self.getValue(v)
        return d
    
    def asJSON(self):
        '''
        recursively return my dict elements
        '''
        return self.reprDict(self.__dict__)
```

You'll find these approaches now integrated in the https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyLoDStorage project which is available at https://pypi.org/project/pylodstorage/

Answer (score 3):

Why are you guys making it so complicated? Here is a simple example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    first: str
    last: str
    age: int

    @property
    def __json__(self):
        return {
            "name": f"{self.first} {self.last}",
            "age": self.age
        }

john = Person("John", "Doe", 42)
print(json.dumps(john, indent=4, default=lambda x: x.__json__))
```

This way you could also serialize nested classes, as `__json__` returns a python object and not a string. No need to use a `JSONEncoder`, as the `default` parameter with a simple lambda also works fine.

I've used `@property` instead of a simple function, as this feels more natural and modern. The `@dataclass` is also just an example, it works for a "normal" class as well.

Comment: possibly because you'd need to define a `__json__` property for each class, which can be sometimes a pain. also, dataclasses provides `asdict` so technically you don't need a `__json__` property at all.

Comment: Sure, but what if you want to represent the json in a different way? Like in this case I combine first and last name. Thje `asdict` would not work for nested elements, right?

Comment: hmm, in that case I would suggest making first and last as `InitVar` (init-only) fields, and setting name field in the `__post_init__` constructor. I think that should hopefully work to represent json in a diff format in this case. Also, i might be wrong but I believe `asdict` works for nested dataclasses as well.

Comment: But that does not work if you change the variables later on.

Comment: Hmm, to best of my understanding it should. can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: [First Comment on main question] "These answers assume that you're doing the serialization yourself, rather than passing the object along to some other module that serializes it. – Kyle Delaney Oct 17, 2019" I think that sums up the issue

Answer (score 2):

jsonweb seems to be the best solution for me. See http://www.jsonweb.info/en/latest/

```
from jsonweb.encode import to_object, dumper

@to_object()
class DataModel(object):
  def __init__(self, id, value):
   self.id = id
   self.value = value

>>> data = DataModel(5, "foo")
>>> dumper(data)
'{"__type__": "DataModel", "id": 5, "value": "foo"}'
```

Comment: Does it work well for nested objects? Including decoding and encoding

Answer (score 2):

I came up with my own solution. Use this method, pass any document (*dict*,*list*, *ObjectId* etc) to serialize.

```
def getSerializable(doc):
    # check if it's a list
    if isinstance(doc, list):
        for i, val in enumerate(doc):
            doc[i] = getSerializable(doc[i])
        return doc

    # check if it's a dict
    if isinstance(doc, dict):
        for key in doc.keys():
            doc[key] = getSerializable(doc[key])
        return doc

    # Process ObjectId
    if isinstance(doc, ObjectId):
        doc = str(doc)
        return doc

    # Use any other custom serializting stuff here...

    # For the rest of stuff
    return doc
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Quinten Cabo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6767994/quinten-cabo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60938758/240845):

```
def sterilize(obj):
    """Make an object more ameniable to dumping as json
    """
    if type(obj) in (str, float, int, bool, type(None)):
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: sterilize(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    list_ret = []
    dict_ret = {}
    for a in dir(obj):
        if a == '__iter__' and callable(obj.__iter__):
            list_ret.extend([sterilize(v) for v in obj])
        elif a == '__dict__':
            dict_ret.update({k: sterilize(v) for k, v in obj.__dict__.items() if k not in ['__module__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__']})
        elif a not in ['__doc__', '__module__']:
            aval = getattr(obj, a)
            if type(aval) in (str, float, int, bool, type(None)):
                dict_ret[a] = aval
            elif a != '__class__' and a != '__objclass__' and isinstance(aval, type):
                dict_ret[a] = sterilize(aval)
    if len(list_ret) == 0:
        if len(dict_ret) == 0:
            return repr(obj)
        return dict_ret
    else:
        if len(dict_ret) == 0:
            return list_ret
    return (list_ret, dict_ret)
```

The differences are

1. Works for any iterable instead of just `list` and `tuple` (it works for NumPy arrays, etc.)
2. Works for dynamic types (ones that contain a `__dict__`).
3. Includes native types `float` and `None` so they don't get converted to string.
4. Classes that have `__dict__` and members will *mostly* work (if the `__dict__` and member names collide, you will only get one - likely the member)
5. Classes that are lists and have members will look like a tuple of the list and a dictionary
6. Python3 (that `isinstance()` call *may* be the only thing that needs changing)

Answer (score 2):

```
class DObject(json.JSONEncoder):
    def delete_not_related_keys(self, _dict):
        for key in ["skipkeys", "ensure_ascii", "check_circular", "allow_nan", "sort_keys", "indent"]:
            try:
                del _dict[key]
            except:
                continue

    def default(self, o):
        if hasattr(o, '__dict__'):
            my_dict = o.__dict__.copy()
            self.delete_not_related_keys(my_dict)
            return my_dict
        else:
            return o

a = DObject()
a.name = 'abdul wahid'
b = DObject()
b.name = a

print(json.dumps(b, cls=DObject))
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked Lost Koder's method the most. I ran into issues when trying to serialize more complex objects whos members/methods aren't serializable. Here's my implementation that works on more objects:

```
class Serializer(object):
    @staticmethod
    def serialize(obj):
        def check(o):
            for k, v in o.__dict__.items():
                try:
                    _ = json.dumps(v)
                    o.__dict__[k] = v
                except TypeError:
                    o.__dict__[k] = str(v)
            return o
        return json.dumps(check(obj).__dict__, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when I tried to store Peewee's model into PostgreSQL `JSONField`.

After struggling for a while, here's the general solution.

The key to my solution is going through Python's source code and realizing that the code documentation (described [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/encoder.py#L96)) already explains how to extend the existing `json.dumps` to support other data types.

Suppose you current have a model that contains some fields that are not serializable to JSON and the model that contains the JSON field originally looks like this:

```
class SomeClass(Model):
    json_field = JSONField()
```

Just define a custom `JSONEncoder` like this:

```
class CustomJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, SomeTypeUnsupportedByJsonDumps):
            return < whatever value you want >
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    @staticmethod
    def json_dumper(obj):
        return json.dumps(obj, cls=CustomJsonEncoder)
```

And then just use it in your `JSONField` like below:

```
class SomeClass(Model):
    json_field = JSONField(dumps=CustomJsonEncoder.json_dumper)
```

The key is the `default(self, obj)` method above. For every single `... is not JSON serializable` complaint you receive from Python, just add code to handle the unserializable-to-JSON type (such as `Enum` or `datetime`)

For example, here's how I support a class inheriting from `Enum`:

```
class TransactionType(Enum):
   CURRENT = 1
   STACKED = 2

   def default(self, obj):
       if isinstance(obj, TransactionType):
           return obj.value
       return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Finally, with the code implemented like above, you can just convert any Peewee models to be a JSON-seriazable object like below:

```
peewee_model = WhateverPeeweeModel()
new_model = SomeClass()
new_model.json_field = model_to_dict(peewee_model)
```

Though the code above was (somewhat) specific to Peewee, but I think:

1. It's applicable to other ORMs (Django, etc) in general
2. Also, if you understood how `json.dumps` works, this solution also works with Python (sans ORM) in general too

Any questions, please post in the comments section. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the object can pe pickled one can use the following two functions to decode and encode an object:

```
def obj_to_json(obj):
    pickled = pickle.dumps(obj)
    coded = base64.b64encode(pickled).decode('utf8')
    return json.dumps(coded)

def json_to_obj(s):
    coded = base64.b64decode(s)
    return pickle.loads(coded)
```

This is for example usefull in combination with `pytest` and `config.cache`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that suits your needs, but using orjson as json and adding a dataclass decorator to your class solves the problem:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass()
class FileItem:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

import orjson as json
x = FileItem("/foo/bar")
json.dumps(x)
# -> returns b'{"fname":"/foo/bar"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small library that serializes an object with all its children to JSON and also parses it back:

https://github.com/tobiasholler/PyJSONSerialization/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install a package, I'd recommend trying [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/), which worked just fine for my project. A nice thing about this package is that it has the same interface as `pickle`, so if you have already been using `pickle` in your project you can simply substitute in `dill` and see if the script runs, without changing any code. So it is a very cheap solution to try!

(Full anti-disclosure: I am in no way affiliated with and have never contributed to the dill project.)

Install the package:

```
pip install dill
```

Then edit your code to import `dill` instead of `pickle`:

```
# import pickle
import dill as pickle
```

Run your script and see if it works. (If it does you may want to clean up your code so that you are no longer shadowing the `pickle` module name!)

Some specifics on datatypes that `dill` can and cannot serialize, from [the project page](https://pypi.org/project/dill/):

> `dill` can pickle the following standard types:
>
> none, type, bool, int, long, float, complex, str, unicode, tuple,
>   list, dict, file, buffer, builtin, both old and new style classes,
>   instances of old and new style classes, set, frozenset, array,
>   functions, exceptions
>
> `dill` can also pickle more ‘exotic’ standard types:
>
> functions with yields, nested functions, lambdas, cell, method,
>   unboundmethod, module, code, methodwrapper, dictproxy,
>   methoddescriptor, getsetdescriptor, memberdescriptor,
>   wrapperdescriptor, xrange, slice, notimplemented, ellipsis, quit
>
> `dill` cannot yet pickle these standard types:
>
> frame, generator, traceback

Answer (score 0):

I see no mention here of serial versioning or backcompat, so I will post my solution which I've been using for a bit. I probably have a lot more to learn from, specifically Java and Javascript are probably more mature than me here but here goes

https://gist.github.com/andy-d/b7878d0044a4242c0498ed6d67fd50fe

Answer (score 0):

To add another option: You can use the `attrs` package and the `asdict` method.

```
class ObjectEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return attr.asdict(o)

json.dumps(objects, cls=ObjectEncoder)
```

and to convert back

```
def from_json(o):
    if '_obj_name' in o:
        type_ = o['_obj_name']
        del o['_obj_name']
        return globals()[type_](**o)
    else:
        return o

data = JSONDecoder(object_hook=from_json).decode(data)
```

class looks like this

```
@attr.s
class Foo(object):
    x = attr.ib()
    _obj_name = attr.ib(init=False, default='Foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [Onur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538391/44330), You possibly want to deal with datetime type like below.
 (in order to handle: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '**dict**' exception.)

```
def datetime_option(value):
    if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
        return value.timestamp()
    else:
        return value.__dict__
```

Usage:

```
def toJSON(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=datetime_option, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need to make our object JSON-compliant, so we can dump it using the standard JSON module. I did it this way:

```
def serialize(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k:serialize(v) for k,v in o.items()}
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return [serialize(e) for e in o]
    if isinstance(o, bytes):
        return o.decode("utf-8")
    return o
```

Answer (score 0):

This function uses recursion to iterate over every part of the dictionary and then calls the **repr**() methods of classes that are not build-in types.

```py
def sterilize(obj):
    object_type = type(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: sterilize(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif object_type in (list, tuple):
        return [sterilize(v) for v in obj]
    elif object_type in (str, int, bool, float):
        return obj
    else:
        return obj.__repr__()
```

Answer (score 0):

We often dump complex dictionaries in JSON format in log files. While most of the fields carry important information, we don't care much about the built-in class objects(for example a `subprocess.Popen` object). Due to presence of unserializable objects like these, call to `json.dumps()` fails.

To get around this, I built a small function that dumps object's string representation instead of dumping the object itself. And if the data structure you are dealing with is too nested, you can specify the nesting maximum level/depth.

```
from time import time

def safe_serialize(obj , max_depth = 2):

    max_level = max_depth

    def _safe_serialize(obj , current_level = 0):

        nonlocal max_level

        # If it is a list
        if isinstance(obj , list):

            if current_level >= max_level:
                return "[...]"

            result = list()
            for element in obj:
                result.append(_safe_serialize(element , current_level + 1))
            return result

        # If it is a dict
        elif isinstance(obj , dict):

            if current_level >= max_level:
                return "{...}"

            result = dict()
            for key , value in obj.items():
                result[f"{_safe_serialize(key , current_level + 1)}"] = _safe_serialize(value , current_level + 1)
            return result

        # If it is an object of builtin class
        elif hasattr(obj , "__dict__"):
            if hasattr(obj , "__repr__"):
                result = f"{obj.__repr__()}_{int(time())}"
            else:
                try:
                    result = f"{obj.__class__.__name__}_object_{int(time())}"
                except:
                    result = f"object_{int(time())}"
            return result

        # If it is anything else
        else:
            return obj

    return _safe_serialize(obj)
```

Since a dictionary can also have unserializable keys, dumping their class name or object representation will lead to all keys with same name, which will throw error as all keys need to have unique name, that is why the current time since epoch is appended to object names with `int(time())`.

This function can be tested with the following nested dictionary with different levels/depths-

```
d = {
    "a" : {
        "a1" : {
            "a11" : {
                "a111" : "some_value" ,
                "a112" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
            "a12" : {
                "a121" : "some_value" ,
                "a122" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
        } ,
        "a2" : {
            "a21" : {
                "a211" : "some_value" ,
                "a212" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
            "a22" : {
                "a221" : "some_value" ,
                "a222" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
        } ,
    } ,
    "b" : {
        "b1" : {
            "b11" : {
                "b111" : "some_value" ,
                "b112" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
            "b12" : {
                "b121" : "some_value" ,
                "b122" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
        } ,
        "b2" : {
            "b21" : {
                "b211" : "some_value" ,
                "b212" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
            "b22" : {
                "b221" : "some_value" ,
                "b222" : "some_value" ,
            } ,
        } ,
    } ,
    "c" : subprocess.Popen("ls -l".split() , stdout = subprocess.PIPE , stderr = subprocess.PIPE) ,
}
```

Running the following will lead to-

```
print("LEVEL 3")
print(json.dumps(safe_serialize(d , 3) , indent = 4))

print("\n\n\nLEVEL 2")
print(json.dumps(safe_serialize(d , 2) , indent = 4))

print("\n\n\nLEVEL 1")
print(json.dumps(safe_serialize(d , 1) , indent = 4))
```

Result:

```
LEVEL 3
{
    "a": {
        "a1": {
            "a11": "{...}",
            "a12": "{...}"
        },
        "a2": {
            "a21": "{...}",
            "a22": "{...}"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "b1": {
            "b11": "{...}",
            "b12": "{...}"
        },
        "b2": {
            "b21": "{...}",
            "b22": "{...}"
        }
    },
    "c": "<Popen: returncode: None args: ['ls', '-l']>"
}



LEVEL 2
{
    "a": {
        "a1": "{...}",
        "a2": "{...}"
    },
    "b": {
        "b1": "{...}",
        "b2": "{...}"
    },
    "c": "<Popen: returncode: None args: ['ls', '-l']>"
}



LEVEL 1
{
    "a": "{...}",
    "b": "{...}",
    "c": "<Popen: returncode: None args: ['ls', '-l']>"
}
```

[NOTE]: Only use this if you don't care about serialization of a built-in class object.

Answer (score -1):

To throw yet another log into a 10-year old fire, I would also offer the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) for this task, assuming you're using Python 3.6+. This works well with [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which is actually a python *builtin* module in 3.7+ onwards.

The `dataclass-wizard` library will convert your object (and all its attributes recursively) to a `dict`, and makes the reverse (de-serialization) pretty straightforward too, with `fromdict`. Also, here is the PyPi link: https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-wizard/.

> *Disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintener of this library.

```py
import dataclass_wizard
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    hello: str
    a_field: int

obj = A('world', 123)
a_dict = dataclass_wizard.asdict(obj)
# {'hello': 'world', 'aField': 123}
```

Or if you wanted a string:

```
a_str = jsons.dumps(dataclass_wizard.asdict(obj))
```

Or if your class extended from `dataclass_wizard.JSONWizard`:

```
a_str = your_object.to_json()
```

Finally, the library also supports dataclasses in `Union` types, which basically means that a `dict` can be de-serialized into an object of either class `C1` or `C2`. For example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard

@dataclass
class Outer(JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        tag_key = 'tag'
        auto_assign_tags = True

    my_string: str
    inner: 'A | B'  # alternate syntax: `inner: typing.Union['A', 'B']`

@dataclass
class A:
    my_field: int

@dataclass
class B:
    my_field: str


my_dict = {'myString': 'test', 'inner': {'tag': 'B', 'myField': 'test'}}
obj = Outer.from_dict(my_dict)

# True
assert repr(obj) == "Outer(my_string='test', inner=B(my_field='test'))"

obj.to_json()
# {"myString": "test", "inner": {"myField": "test", "tag": "B"}}
```

Comment: I *suppose* it could be that I didn't have a disclaimer.. if so, just fixed that.

Answer (score -1):

Whomever wants to use basic conversion without an external library, it is simply how you can override `__iter__` & `__str__` functions of the custom class using following way.

```py
class JSONCustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return obj.__dict__


class Student:
    def __init__(self, name: str, slug: str):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from {
            "name": self.name,
            "age": self.age,
        }.items()

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(
            self.__dict__, cls=JSONCustomEncoder, ensure_ascii=False
        )
```

Use the object by wrapping in a dict(), so that data remains preserved.

```py
s = Student("aman", 24)
dict(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that there is no "standardized" way to perform Serialization and Deserialization in Python (compare what Python has to offer to Rust which is an alternative language which I happen to know about which does Serialization and Deserialization well) I think what would be helpful is to have an answer which collects together a summary of the possible approaches along with their advantages, disadvantages and performance comparisons.

I cannot provide all this information myself, at least not all at once. So I will start off by providing some information and leave this answer for others to edit and contribute to. I will provide a summary of the most notable answers thus far. For the ones I have missed please freely edit this question or comment and someone will update it. (Hopefully)

When this becomes "production ready" I will clean up this preamble to remove it. My aim would be for this to become a long-term reference which provides the relevant information succinctly, rather than have it be distributed across a large number of individual answers, each arguing their case for why they should be used.

## General

- Serialization is a many-to-1 operation, meaning that once serialized type information is lost and the same serialized string could represent infinitly many possible parent types. The obvious example is that of a `Set` and a `list`. These are two different objects (types), which could contain the same set of elements, would be serialized in the same way.
- Many languages solve this problem by explicitly providing type information as part of the deserialization function call. For example `Type::deserialize()` or `deserialize(..., type=Type)`. This is not code for any particular language, it is simply here to present how type information might be present in code.

## json

**Advantages:**

- Native to Python
- Will serialize basic types: `dict, list, str, int, float, bool, None`

**Disadvantages:**

- Does not serialize recursively, meaning if one Python object contains another then the containing object is not serializable
- Does not serialize common types like `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date`

## jsons

**Advantages:**

- Correctly serializes and deserializes recursively nested types (?)
- Correctly serializes and deserializes common types like `datetime` objects (?)

**Disadvantages:**

- Slow (?)

## jsonpickle

**Advantages:**

- Correctly serializes and deserializes recursively nested types (?)
- Correctly serializes and deserializes common types like `datetime` objects (?)

**Disadvantages:**

- Type information is present in the encoded (serialized) output.
- This means that the encoded output is more verbose, contains fields that you might not expect to see (type info) and the encoding is "special" to both Python and the `jsonpickle` library.
- If you deserialize this in another languages or using another Python library, you will obviously not have access to the same behaviours. (In other words the code you write will behave differently. This is sort of obvious and goes without saying.)
- You can suppress the type information using an argument `unpicklable=False`
- Might be slow? (Citation required: please edit to add performance comparisons)

## inheriting from `dict`, using Python's inbuilt json library

**Advantages:**

- Works without requiring other libraries
- Minimal boilerplate

**Disadvantages:**

- Does not work for non-serializable types like `datetime`
- Does not work for nested types (?)
- Since your type is probably not actually a `dict` but something else, this violates fundamental principles of OOP design

** Considerations:**

- You can use `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods so that it will use the dict values for any undefined attributes, see answer by Sunding Wei

## Use composition over inheritance, aka wrap a `dict`

**Advantages:**

- Does not violate OOP design compared to above alternative
- Works for nested types, but requires a lot of boilerplate, better for things that do not have nesting

**Disadvantages:**

- Unless more boilerplate is added, accessing elements of the `dict` requires more code, and the resulting code is less intuitive. If the `dict` object is named `data_dict` rather than accessing `my_class.my_field` one has to `my_class.data_dict.my_field`
- Properties or getters/setters can mitigate this but that requires maintainance of 2N functions for N fields
- Requires adding `from_dict` class method for deserialization and `__json__` or `to_json` for serializing
- As such, this is a more manual operation compared to the previously presented examples. That might be preferable/acceptable if explicit code is prefered for some cases where there is no nesting of types

## Manual implementation by returning a `dict` as an interface type

- See answer by Martin Thoma, it is similar to the above option of wrapping a `dict`

**Advantages:**

- Uses explicit type information from `TYPE.from_json` class methods
- Allows creating a class with explicitly named fields rather than keys in a dictionary

**Disadvantages:**

- Requires two step loading instead of a single line of code
- Requires some boilerplate
- Since the serialization is being done by relying on conversion of the class to a `dict` structure, might consider using above method more straightforward
- Does not work in cases where the fields include types like `datetime`

## subclassing `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder`

**Advantages:**

- Leverages Python native json library
- others?

**Disadvantages:**

- Not a 1 line solution
- Requires creating a class to serialize and deserialize every type you want to be able to serialize and deserialize

Side note: This looks like it should be the "canonical" choice ... but I'm not completely sure I understand it and the fact that this weird "hook" think is required makes me suspect it's perhaps not that generalizable? Maybe someone else can edit this section and clarify?

## `default=vars`

**Advantage:**

- Very quickly allows serialization of custom objects

**Disadvantage:**

- Only works for types serializable with native `json` library, does not work for types like `datetime`
- Does not work for nested types (?)

## json-fix

See answer by Jeff Hykin

## simplejson

todo

## json-tricks

todo

## jsonweb

todo

Answer (score -2):

There are many approaches to this problem.  'ObjDict'  (pip install objdict) is another.  There is an emphasis on providing javascript like objects which can also act like dictionaries to best handle data loaded from JSON, but there are other features which can be useful as well.  This provides another alternative solution to the original problem.

Answer (score -2):

I chose to use decorators to solve the datetime object serialization problem.
Here is my code:

```
#myjson.py
#Author: jmooremcc 7/16/2017

import json
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
"""
This module uses decorators to serialize date objects using json
The filename is myjson.py
In another module you simply add the following import statement:
    from myjson import json

json.dumps and json.dump will then correctly serialize datetime and date 
objects
"""

def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        serial = str(obj)
        return serial
    raise TypeError ("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))


def FixDumps(fn):
    def hook(obj):
        return fn(obj, default=json_serial)

    return hook

def FixDump(fn):
    def hook(obj, fp):
        return fn(obj,fp, default=json_serial)

    return hook


json.dumps=FixDumps(json.dumps)
json.dump=FixDump(json.dump)


if __name__=="__main__":
    today=datetime.now()
    data={'atime':today, 'greet':'Hello'}
    str=json.dumps(data)
    print str
```

By importing the above module, my other modules use json in a normal way (without specifying the default keyword) to serialize data that contains date time objects. The datetime serializer code is automatically called for json.dumps and json.dump.