# Serializing class instance to JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization, pickle

I am trying to create a JSON string representation of a class instance and having difficulty. Let's say the class is built like this:

```
class testclass:
    value1 = "a"
    value2 = "b"
```

A call to the json.dumps is made like this:

```
t = testclass()
json.dumps(t)
```

It is failing and telling me that the testclass is not JSON serializable.

```
TypeError: <__main__.testclass object at 0x000000000227A400> is not JSON serializable
```

I have also tried using the pickle module :

```
t = testclass()
print(pickle.dumps(t, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
```

And it gives class instance information but not a serialized content of the class instance.

```
b'\x80\x03c__main__\ntestclass\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02b.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343535/easiest-way-to-serialize-a-simple-class-object-with-simplejson

Comment: Use one line, `s = json.dumps(obj, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)`, to serialize object's instance variables (`self.value1`, `self.value2`, ...). Its the simplest and the most straight forward way. It will serialize nested object structures. The `default` function is called when any given object is not directly serializable. You can also look at my answer below. I found the popular answers unnecessarily complex, which were probably true quite a long time back.

Comment: Your `testclass` has no `__init__()` method, so all instances will share the same two class attributes (`value1` and `value2`) defined in the class statement. Do you understand the difference between a class and an instance of one?

Comment: There is a python library for this https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle
(commenting since answer is too below in the thread and wont be reachable.)

Answer (score 312, accepted):

The basic problem is that the JSON encoder `json.dumps()` only knows how to serialize a limited set of object types by default, all built-in types.  List here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

One good solution would be to make your class inherit from `JSONEncoder` and then implement the `JSONEncoder.default()` function, and make that function emit the correct JSON for your class.

A simple solution would be to call `json.dumps()` on the `.__dict__` member of that instance.  That is a standard Python `dict` and if your class is simple it will be JSON serializable.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

foo = Foo()
s = json.dumps(foo) # raises TypeError with "is not JSON serializable"

s = json.dumps(foo.__dict__) # s set to: {"x":1, "y":2}
```

The above approach is discussed in this blog posting:

[Serializing arbitrary Python objects to JSON using _*dict*_](http://www.marcstober.com/blog/2007/07/07/serializing-arbitrary-python-objects-to-json-using-__dict__/)

And, of course, Python offers a built-in function that accesses `.__dict__` for you, called `vars()`.

So the above example can also be done as:

```
s = json.dumps(vars(foo)) # s set to: {"x":1, "y":2}
```

Comment: I tried this. The end result of a call to json.dumps(t.__dict__) is just {}.

Comment: That is because your class doesn't have a `.__init__()` method function, so your class instance has an empty dictionary.  In other words, `{}` is the correct result for your example code.

Comment: Thanks. This does the trick. I added a simple __init__ with no parameters and now calling the json.dumps(t.__dict__) returns proper data in the format of:
{"value2": "345", "value1": "123"}

I had seen posts like this before, wasn't sure whether I needed a custom serializer for members, needing __init__ wasn't mentioned explicitly or I missed it. Thank you.

Comment: This work for a single class but not with related classes objets

Comment: @NwawelAIroume: True. If you have an object which e.g. is containing multiple objects in a list the error is still `is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @gies0r so, in that case how could you get the json of those multiple objects?

Comment: Can someone provide a good reference for the approach of inheriting from JSONEncoder and then implementing the JSONEncoder.default() function?

Comment: Also, what do I do if I have to get the JSON representation of not just 1 object but a list of objects?

Comment: the `__dict__` approach, Works like a charm, just the class name gets appended to the attribute names. Which in my case is ok. Using Python3.5 on Mac

Answer (score 91):

There's one way that works great for me that you can try out:

`json.dumps()` can take an optional parameter **default** where you can specify a custom serializer function for unknown types, which in my case looks like

```
def serialize(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, date):
        serial = obj.isoformat()
        return serial

    if isinstance(obj, time):
        serial = obj.isoformat()
        return serial

    return obj.__dict__
```

First two ifs are for date and time serialization
and then there is a `obj.__dict__` returned for any other object.

the final call looks like:

```
json.dumps(myObj, default=serialize)
```

It's especially good when you are serializing a collection and you don't want to call `__dict__` explicitly for every object. Here it's done for you automatically.

So far worked so good for me, looking forward for your thoughts.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'serialize' is not defined`. Any tips?

Comment: Very nice. Just for classes that have slots: `try:
      dict = obj.__dict__
    except AttributeError:
      dict = {s: getattr(obj, s) for s in obj.__slots__ if hasattr(obj, s)}
    return dict`

Comment: @Fantastory Why `try-except` instead of just checking with `hasattr(obj, "__dict__")`?  Much cleaner and professional, IMHO.

Comment: Is not try the python way?

Answer (score 81):

You can specify the `default` named parameter in the `json.dumps()` function:

```
json.dumps(obj, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)
```

Explanation:

Form the docs ([2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage), [3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage)):

```
``default(obj)`` is a function that should return a serializable version
of obj or raise TypeError. The default simply raises TypeError.
```

(Works on Python 2.7 and Python 3.x)

Note: In this case you need `instance` variables and not `class` variables, as the example in the question tries to do. (I am assuming the asker meant `class instance` to be an object of a class)

I learned this first from @phihag's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408647/convert-dynamic-python-object-to-json). Found it to be the simplest and cleanest way to do the job.

Comment: This worked for me, but because of datetime.date members I changed it slightly: `default=lambda x: getattr(x, '__dict__', str(x))`

Comment: @Dakota nice work-around; `datetime.date` is a C implementation hence it has no `__dict__` attribute. IMHO for uniformity's sake, `datetime.date` should be having it...

Answer (score 31):

Using [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

```
import jsonpickle

object = YourClass()
json_object = jsonpickle.encode(object)
```

Comment: `jsonpickle` worked fine until I ran into `Metaclasses` [#105](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle/pull/105). `Enum(s)` went through a weird serialisation

Answer (score 25):

I just do:

```
data=json.dumps(myobject.__dict__)
```

This is not the full answer, and if you have some sort of complicated object class you certainly will not get everything. However I use this for some of my simple objects.

One that it works really well on is the "options" class that you get from the OptionParser module. 
Here it is along with the JSON request itself.

```
  def executeJson(self, url, options):
        data=json.dumps(options.__dict__)
        if options.verbose:
            print data
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        return requests.post(url, data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You might want to remove self, if you are not using this inside a class.

Comment: That will work okay, as long as the object isn't composed of other objects.

Answer (score 8):

JSON is not really meant for serializing arbitrary Python objects.  It's great for serializing `dict` objects, but the `pickle` module is really what you should be using in general.  Output from `pickle` is not really human-readable, but it should unpickle just fine.  If you insist on using JSON, you could check out the `jsonpickle` module, which is an interesting hybrid approach.

https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle

Comment: The main problem I see with pickle is that it's a Python-specific format, while JSON is a platform-independant format. JSON is specially useful if you're writing either a web application or a backend for some mobile application.
That having been said, thanks for pointing out to jsonpickle.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Doesn't jsonpickle still export to JSON, just not very human readable?

Comment: The question isn't about serialization, it is about serializing to JSON. There are a lot of reasons for doing that and pickle would be a horrible tool for most of them.

Answer (score 8):

Python3.x

The best aproach I could reach with my knowledge was this.
Note that this code treat set() too.
This approach is generic just needing the extension of class (in the second example).
Note that I'm just doing it to files, but it's easy to modify the behavior to your taste.

However this is a CoDec.

With a little more work you can construct your class in other ways.
I assume a default constructor to instance it, then I update the class dict.

```
import json
import collections


class JsonClassSerializable(json.JSONEncoder):

    REGISTERED_CLASS = {}

    def register(ctype):
        JsonClassSerializable.REGISTERED_CLASS[ctype.__name__] = ctype

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, collections.Set):
            return dict(_set_object=list(obj))
        if isinstance(obj, JsonClassSerializable):
            jclass = {}
            jclass["name"] = type(obj).__name__
            jclass["dict"] = obj.__dict__
            return dict(_class_object=jclass)
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    def json_to_class(self, dct):
        if '_set_object' in dct:
            return set(dct['_set_object'])
        elif '_class_object' in dct:
            cclass = dct['_class_object']
            cclass_name = cclass["name"]
            if cclass_name not in self.REGISTERED_CLASS:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "Class {} not registered in JSON Parser"
                    .format(cclass["name"])
                )
            instance = self.REGISTERED_CLASS[cclass_name]()
            instance.__dict__ = cclass["dict"]
            return instance
        return dct

    def encode_(self, file):
        with open(file, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(
                self.__dict__, outfile,
                cls=JsonClassSerializable,
                indent=4,
                sort_keys=True
            )

    def decode_(self, file):
        try:
            with open(file, 'r') as infile:
                self.__dict__ = json.load(
                    infile,
                    object_hook=self.json_to_class
                )
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Persistence load failed "
                  "'{}' do not exists".format(file)
                  )


class C(JsonClassSerializable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.mill = "s"


JsonClassSerializable.register(C)


class B(JsonClassSerializable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1230
        self.c = C()


JsonClassSerializable.register(B)


class A(JsonClassSerializable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = {1, 2}
        self.c = B()

JsonClassSerializable.register(A)

A().encode_("test")
b = A()
b.decode_("test")
print(b.a)
print(b.b)
print(b.c.a)
```

---

**Edit**

With some more of research I found a way to generalize without the need of the **SUPERCLASS** register method call, using a **metaclass**

```
import json
import collections

REGISTERED_CLASS = {}

class MetaSerializable(type):

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.__name__ not in REGISTERED_CLASS:
            REGISTERED_CLASS[cls.__name__] = cls
        return super(MetaSerializable, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class JsonClassSerializable(json.JSONEncoder, metaclass=MetaSerializable):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, collections.Set):
            return dict(_set_object=list(obj))
        if isinstance(obj, JsonClassSerializable):
            jclass = {}
            jclass["name"] = type(obj).__name__
            jclass["dict"] = obj.__dict__
            return dict(_class_object=jclass)
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    def json_to_class(self, dct):
        if '_set_object' in dct:
            return set(dct['_set_object'])
        elif '_class_object' in dct:
            cclass = dct['_class_object']
            cclass_name = cclass["name"]
            if cclass_name not in REGISTERED_CLASS:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "Class {} not registered in JSON Parser"
                    .format(cclass["name"])
                )
            instance = REGISTERED_CLASS[cclass_name]()
            instance.__dict__ = cclass["dict"]
            return instance
        return dct

    def encode_(self, file):
        with open(file, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(
                self.__dict__, outfile,
                cls=JsonClassSerializable,
                indent=4,
                sort_keys=True
            )

    def decode_(self, file):
        try:
            with open(file, 'r') as infile:
                self.__dict__ = json.load(
                    infile,
                    object_hook=self.json_to_class
                )
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Persistence load failed "
                  "'{}' do not exists".format(file)
                  )


class C(JsonClassSerializable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.mill = "s"


class B(JsonClassSerializable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1230
        self.c = C()


class A(JsonClassSerializable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = {1, 2}
        self.c = B()


A().encode_("test")
b = A()
b.decode_("test")
print(b.a)
# 1
print(b.b)
# {1, 2}
print(b.c.a)
# 1230
print(b.c.c.mill)
# s
```

Comment: I love it. This is amazing implementation. I have just 1 question if I may, why did you use _call_ method and not _new_ method in the meta class? I ask, because the _call_ method gets called every time a new instance is created, so the code tries to register the class for every new instance. Not a big deal, and as I wrote I love this implementation it seems really great :-)

Answer (score 6):

This can be easily handled with [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), as it already has this functionality built-in.

Option 1: normal way

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class testclass(BaseModel):
    value1: str = "a"
    value2: str = "b"

test = testclass()

>>> print(test.json(indent=4))
{
    "value1": "a",
    "value2": "b"
}
```

Option 2: using pydantic's dataclass

```
import json
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic.json import pydantic_encoder

@dataclass
class testclass:
    value1: str = "a"
    value2: str = "b"

test = testclass()
>>> print(json.dumps(test, indent=4, default=pydantic_encoder))
{
    "value1": "a",
    "value2": "b"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe instead of inheritance as suggested in accepted answer, it's better to use polymorphism. Otherwise you have to have a big if else statement to customize encoding of every object. That means create a generic default encoder for JSON as:

```
def jsonDefEncoder(obj):
   if hasattr(obj, 'jsonEnc'):
      return obj.jsonEnc()
   else: #some default behavior
      return obj.__dict__
```

and then have a `jsonEnc()` function in each class you want to serialize. e.g.

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self,lengthInFeet):
      self.lengthInFeet=lengthInFeet
   def jsonEnc(self):
      return {'lengthInMeters': lengthInFeet * 0.3 } # each foot is 0.3 meter
```

Then you call `json.dumps(classInstance,default=jsonDefEncoder)`

Comment: This is the correct answer. The class knows how to serialize itself. It is too bad that you can't just pass the method name directly to json.dumps

Answer (score 5):

Here are two simple functions for serialization of any non-sophisticated classes, nothing fancy as explained before.

I use this for configuration type stuff because I can add new members to the classes with no code adjustments.

```
import json

class SimpleClass:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, c=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

def serialize_json(instance=None, path=None):
    dt = {}
    dt.update(vars(instance))

    with open(path, "w") as file:
        json.dump(dt, file)

def deserialize_json(cls=None, path=None):
    def read_json(_path):
        with open(_path, "r") as file:
            return json.load(file)

    data = read_json(path)

    instance = object.__new__(cls)

    for key, value in data.items():
        setattr(instance, key, value)

    return instance

# Usage: Create class and serialize under Windows file system.
write_settings = SimpleClass(a=1, b=2, c=3)
serialize_json(write_settings, r"c:\temp\test.json")

# Read back and rehydrate.
read_settings = deserialize_json(SimpleClass, r"c:\temp\test.json")

# results are the same.
print(vars(write_settings))
print(vars(read_settings))

# output:
# {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}
# {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Hey @GBGOLC,
Thanks for that awesome piece of code! I've tried to implement it with json.loads and dumps since there aren't any files where I'm using the code. I'm struggling to decode the Vehicle class in my example, which refers to wheels.
[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jH6YKXv_aarxLcDN9VwZIsJx30eb-PoY/view?usp=sharing) how I've changed it.
Help much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I solved my own problem: since decode_ changes the instance it is passed, there was no return value to pass to a new instance. Your code was fine and only my way of calling decode_ needed changing.
Thanks again for the great code!

Answer (score 3):

Use arbitrary, extensible object, and then serialize it to JSON:

```
import json

class Object(object):
    pass

response = Object()
response.debug = []
response.result = Object()

# Any manipulations with the object:
response.debug.append("Debug string here")
response.result.body = "404 Not Found"
response.result.code = 404

# Proper JSON output, with nice formatting:
print(json.dumps(response, indent=4, default=lambda x: x.__dict__))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers on how to get started on doing this. But there are some things to keep in mind:

- What if the instance is nested inside a large data structure?
- What if also want the class name?
- What if you want to deserialize the instance?
- What if you're using `__slots__` instead of `__dict__`?
- What if you just don't want to do it yourself?

[json-tricks](https://github.com/mverleg/pyjson_tricks) is a library (that I made and others contributed to) which has been able to do this for quite a while. For example:

```
class MyTestCls:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

cls_instance = MyTestCls(s='ub', dct={'7': 7})

json = dumps(cls_instance, indent=4)
instance = loads(json)
```

You'll get your instance back. Here the json looks like this:

```
{
    "__instance_type__": [
        "json_tricks.test_class",
        "MyTestCls"
    ],
    "attributes": {
        "s": "ub",
        "dct": {
            "7": 7
        }
    }
}
```

If you like to make your own solution, you might look at the source of `json-tricks` so as not to forget some special cases (like `__slots__`).

It also does other types like numpy arrays, datetimes, complex numbers; it also allows for comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *Jsonic* for to serialize pretty much anything to JSON:

https://github.com/OrrBin/Jsonic

Example:

```
class TestClass:
def __init__(self):
    self.x = 1
    self.y = 2

instance = TestClass()
s = serialize(instance): # instance s set to: {"x":1, "y":2}
d = deserialize(s) # d is a new class instance of TestClass
```

*Jsonic* has some nice features like declaring class attributes transient and type safe deserialization.

(A few years late with the answer, but i think it might help others)

Answer (score 2):

An approach which I have been using in my Flask app to serialize Class instance to JSON response.

[Github project for reference](https://github.com/prayagkr/flask_bootstrap)

```
from json import JSONEncoder
import json
from typing import List

class ResponseEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__

class ListResponse:
    def __init__(self, data: List):
        self.data = data
        self.count = len(data)

class A:
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        self.message = message

class B:
    def __init__(self, record: A):
        self.record = record

class C:
    def __init__(self, data: B):
        self.data = data
```

Now create an instance of A, B, C then encode.

```
data_a = A('Test Data')
data_b = B(data_a)
data_c = C(data_b)

response = ResponseEncoder().encode(data_c)
json_response = json.loads(response)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "data": {
        "record": {
            "message": "Test Data"
        }
    }
}
```

**For list type response**

```
records = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
list_response = ListResponse(records)
response = ResponseEncoder().encode(list_response)
json_response = json.loads(response)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "data": [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
    ],
    "count": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another really simple and elegant approach that can be applied here which is to just subclass 'dict' since it is serializable by default.

```
from json import dumps

class Response(dict):
    def __init__(self, status_code, body):
        super().__init__(
            status_code = status_code,
            body = body
        )

r = Response()
dumps(r)
```

Comment: This leads to some weird outcomes, which are probably OK, just confusing:
`r = Response(200, 'blah'); r['a'] = 1; r.b = 2` results in `r == {'status_code': 200, 'body': 'blah', 'a': 1}` and `r.__dict__ == {'b': 2}`. I would love to know where `dict` actually stores it's keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

I made a function for this, it works pretty well:

```py
def serialize(x,*args,**kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('default',lambda x:getattr(x,'__dict__',dict((k,getattr(x,k) if not callable(getattr(x,k)) else repr(getattr(x,k))) for k in dir(x) if not (k.startswith('__') or isinstance(getattr(x,k),x.__class__)))))
    return json.dumps(x,*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `objprint`, which is a light-weighted library to print Python objects, and it supports json output.

```
pip install objprint
```

```py
from objprint import objjson
t = testclass()
json_obj = objjson(t)
print(json.dumps(json_obj))
```

`objjson` basically converts an arbitrary object to a jsonifiable object, with a special key `.type` for it's original Python type, if it's not builtin type like dict, list etc.

If you simply want to print it, you can use `op` which is normally used to print objects in a human-readable format.

```py
from objprint import op
t = testclass()
op(t, format="json", indent=2)

# If you want to dump to a file
with open("my_obj.json", "w") as f:
    # This is the same usage as print
    op(t, format="json", file=f)
```