# Passing objects between python and java via json

Tags: java, python, json, string

I would need some interprocess communication via stdin and stdout between a python script and a java engine.

Is there anyway I could convert a python object into JSON and converting this whole object as a string to be passed via stdin to Java and converting that string back to JSON for processing before returning it back to python as a JSON object converted via a string

In Summary this is what I need

```
Python Object-> JSON -> String -> Stdin -> String -> JSON in java ->processing -> JSON -> String -> Stdout -> python -> String -> JSON
```

Any other solutions that satisfy this condition is also acceptable.

I would just like to know if its possible to send a JSON object via stdin or what are the possible ways to do it

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am not asking for any codes. I just would like to know if its possible or is it possible to do it this way

Comment: Frankly, this reads like a code request to me as well. You should probably edit your question to properly indicate that you wish to know whether or not interprocess communication is possible between a python script and a java engine, via `stdin` and `stdout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252138/1392195) is how you would convert a Python object to JSON, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) is an article showing how to use JSR 353 to parse JSON, and consider using [sockets](http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/07/socket-programming-tutorial.html) for IPC.