# TypeError: 'tasks:meta:newtask' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python

I am trying to dump this json -

```
{'total_run_count': 9, 'task': 'tasks.add', 'enabled': True, 'schedule': {'period': 'seconds', 'every': 3}, 'kwargs': {'max_targets': 100}, 'running': False, 'options': {}, 'delete_key': 'deleted:tasks:meta:newtask', 'name': b'tasks:meta:newtask', 'last_run_at': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 19, 9, 50, 162098), 'args': ['3', '2'], 'key': 'tasks:meta:newtask'}
```

and it fails for the key 'name'. I have decoded it in utf-8 but still not luck. I am getting the following error.

TypeError: 'tasks:meta:newtask' is not JSON serializable

what is not serializable about the above string ? I am clueless.

Comment: try json.dumps(yourObject.__dict__), check answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252010/serializing-python-object-instance-to-json

Comment: "Still not luck" -- meaning what, *exactly*? When I try to reproduce this, and have decoded the bytestring, what I then have is the following: `TypeError: datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 19, 9, 50, 162098) is not JSON serializable` -- which it's indeed not. But that's a different error, and your question should reflect that.

Comment: @Shamik, ...show us *how* you're trying to decode the object (and then serialize the result), so we can tell that it's done correctly.

Comment: I have a custom decoder inside which i am handling for datetime objects. But somehow even after decoding the byte string i am getting the above error. The error doesn't have the byte,  check .

Comment: @Shamik, *show us*: Provide a reproducer people who aren't you can run that generates your errors even after your attempts to avoid it. Right now, you're *saying* that you fixed some relevant issues, but without seeing the details of the implementation, we have no possible way of finding still-outstanding problems. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "name" value in your dict is a `bytes` object, not string. You have to decode it or you can write your [custom JSON encoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder):

```
import json

def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, bytes):
        return o.decode()
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

data = {'name': b'tasks:meta:newtask'}
json.JSONEncoder(default=default).encode(data)
```

Comment: Not the only problem in this data -- at least with Python 3.4.5, `datetime.datetime` objects aren't JSON-serializable either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that's a good point! It's easy to extend the `default` function to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how that item is displayed in the dictionary:

```
'name': b'tasks:meta:newtask'
```

That leading `b` indicates that 'tasks:meta:newtask' is a *byte string*, not a regular character string.  JSON is telling you that it doesn't know how to handle a byte string object.

Does it really need to be a byte string?  If not, you should convert it to a regular string before calling json dump.

Comment: I have handled it by decoding it in utf-8. If you see the error it doesn't have the leading b.

Comment: _I have handled it_ So you've solved your problem then?  Great!

Comment: @Shamik, if what you're actually trying to JSON-serialize differs from what's given in your question (such as because you're modifying the bytestring to be a character string instead), *update the question to reflect the actual data* -- but make sure (completely, 100% sure) that it can be reproduced in that state.