# How to convert variables to json?

Tags: python, json

```
ip_adrs_ve100_lst = ['5.5.5.1', '5.5.5.2']
at_ip_1 = '10.10.10.1'
at_ip_2 = '10.10.10.2'
```

to json format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing python object instance to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252010/serializing-python-object-instance-to-json)

Answer (score 3):

Just create a dictionary, and then convert it to json:

```
data_dict = {'ip_adrs_ve100_lst': ['5.5.5.1', '5.5.5.2'],
        'at_ip_1': '10.10.10.1',
        'at_ip_2': '10.10.10.2'}
import json
to_json = json.dumps(data_dict)
```

Comment: `vars` is the name of a Python built-in function, so creating a variable with the same name is a poor programming practice and ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention, add `ensure_ascii=False` to `json.dumps()` call to ensure that the returned instance is always `unicode`:

```
import json

my_dict = {
    'ip_adrs_ve100_lst': ['5.5.5.1', '5.5.5.2'],
    'at_ip_1': '10.10.10.1',
    'at_ip_2': '10.10.10.2'
}
my_json = json.dumps(my_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
```