# how to transform normal strings in json format

Tags: python, json

i have to acess some variables and transform them back to json format.

They are stored in columns, i have:

```
name = request.values['name']
age = request.values['age']
```

This gives me back something like:

```
John 23
```

How to transform this to:

```
'{"name":"John", "age":"23"}'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978566/how-to-convert-variables-to-json

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (read "dump string"):

```
json.dumps(request.values)
```

If you only want a subset of the dictionary you can use:

```
json.dumps({k: request.values[k] for k in ('name', 'age')})
```