# python - How Popen stdout can return object

Tags: python

I have a python script `(test.py)` and it will call another python script `(x.py)` to do something and I would like the `x.py` can return the object "Person" to `test.py`.

**test.py**:

```
cmd= "python /usr/example/x.py"
command= Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

**x.py**:

```
--The following coding is used to assign a name to object "person"
person = people.name("Peter")  
printAreeter
```

Is there any ways that can archive my goals?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quote:
this is how to dump to json

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

foo = Foo()
s = json.dumps(foo) # raises TypeError with "is not JSON serializable"

s = json.dumps(foo.__dict__) # s set to: {"x":1, "y":2}
```

this is how to read it back:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,*kwags):
        if kwags == None:
            self.x = 1
            self.y = 2
        else:
            self.x = kwags.get("x")
            self.y = kwags.get("y")    
foo = Foo(json.loads("{"x":1, "y":2}"))
```

from:[class serieslization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252010/serializing-class-instance-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

solution:

1 use json return and read it back to the object

2 is it possible to try import the function or class in x.py and u can run the func as native func or classes

3 if not i suppose u r running on another machine, i strongly recommend paramiko library

Comment: How I can do it on solution 1? Can you give me some example?

Also, is there any way that stdout can directly output an object?

Comment: sure please refer to my lastest anser, BTＷ　how to post code on  comments?