# Transform a class with other calsses as attributes in a dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am recreating a structure of a json file using classes and classes as attributes of the parent class (this allows me to use set methods for easing the process):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,):
        self.test = "something of A"
    def set_test():
        pass # some function here to set test from B



class B(object):
    def __init__(self,):
        self.test2 = A() # This is the A class that I wan't to access
        self.test3 = "something of B"



g = B()
g.__dict__
```

The result is this:

```
{'test2': <__main__.A at 0x7fda2d2fd9a0>, 'test3': 'something of B'}
```

I would instead want to get the dict object also of the class as an attribute:

```
{'test2': {'test': 'something of A'}, 'test3': 'something of B'}
```

I know that I can do: `g['test2'] = g['test2'].__dict__` but I was wondering if there is an automated way to get resolve as dictionaries all the classes linked as attributes.

> NOTE: I want to be able to access the methods of A from B otherwise I
> would have directly created a dictionary for B

Comment: **if there is an automated way** what's the problem with writting your own function? I mean you just put `g.__dict__['test2'].__dict__` in `test`

Comment: Does this answer your question maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252010/serializing-class-instance-to-json

Comment: `self.test2` refering to object `A()` not `A().__dict__`

Comment: Why don't you make custom `getter`

Comment: @Countour-Integral I have to do it for all my sub classes and they can be more then 800

Comment: @Epsi95 I know this is how it is supposed to be, so I can access the function of A from B

Comment: @TheOriginalOdis thanks this really could be a backup plan. Very grateful.