# json.dumps not working with custom python object

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am not able to serialize a custom object in python 3 .
Below is the explanation and code

```
packages= []
data = {
    "simplefield": "value1",
    "complexfield": packages,
}
```

where packages is a list of `custom object Library`.
`Library object` is a class as below (I have also sub-classed `json.JSONEncoder` but it is not helping )

```
class Library(json.JSONEncoder):
def __init__(self, name):
    print("calling Library constructor ")
    self.name = name

def default(self, object):
    print("calling default method ")
    if isinstance(object, Library):
        return {
            "name": object.name
        }
    else:
        raiseExceptions("Object is not instance of Library")
```

Now I am calling `json.dumps(data)` but it is throwing below exception.

```
TypeError: Object of type `Library` is not JSON serializable
```

It seems `"calling default method"` is not printed meaning, `Library.default` method is not called

Can anybody please help here ?

I have also referred to [Serializing class instance to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252010/serializing-class-instance-to-json) but its is not helping much

Comment: What is your input and what is the output yu wish to have?

Comment: It should serialize the Library object . Its implementation is given in default method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting `json.JSONEncoder` will not make a class serializable. You should define your encoder separately and then provide the encoder instance in the `json.dumps` call.

See an example approach below

```
import json
from typing import Any


class Library:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("calling Library constructor ")
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        # I have just created a serialized version of the object
        return '{"name": "%s"}' % self.name

# Create your custom encoder
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        # Encode differently for different types
        return str(o) if isinstance(o, Library) else super().default(o)


packages = [Library("package1"), Library("package2")]
data = {
    "simplefield": "value1",
    "complexfield": packages,
}
#Use your encoder while serializing
print(json.dumps(data, cls=CustomEncoder))
```

Output was like:

```
{"simplefield": "value1", "complexfield": ["{\"name\": \"package1\"}", "{\"name\": \"package2\"}"]}
```

Comment: Hi Kris, how to remove this: double quotes "" and escape character \ inside complexfield ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `default` parameter of `json.dump`:

```
def default(obj):
  if isinstance(obj, Library):
      return {"name": obj.name}
  raise TypeError(f"Can't serialize {obj!r}.")

json.dumps(data, default=default)
```