# JSON Encoding with Django adding extra \\ characters

Tags: python, django, json, django-models

I'm trying to create a function that will convert a dictionary containing a message and a Django model instance into JSON, that I can pass back to the client.  For example, I have the model Test defined in models.py.

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):
    test_field = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I've defined this extension of the simplejson JSONEncoder based on the this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249792/json-serializing-django-models-with-simplejson):

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.utils.simplejson import dumps, loads, JSONEncoder
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.db import models
from django.utils.functional import curry

class DjangoJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
            # `default` must return a python serializable
            # structure, the easiest way is to load the JSON
            # string produced by `serialize` and return it
            return loads(serialize('json', obj))
        if isinstance(obj, models.Model):
            #do the same as above by making it a queryset first
            set_obj = [obj]
            set_str = serialize('json', set_obj)
            #eliminate brackets in the beginning and the end 
            str_obj = set_str[1:len(set_str)-2]
            return str_obj
        return JSONEncoder.default(self,obj)

# partial function, we can now use dumps(my_dict) instead
# of dumps(my_dict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
dumps = curry(dumps, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Then I go about creating an instance of this along with a status message:

```
t = Test(test_field="hello")
d = {"entry": t, "message": "Congratulations"}
json = dumps(d)
```

The contents of json are:

```
{"entry": "{\\"pk\\": null, \\"model\\": \\"hours.test\\", \\"fields\\": {\\"test_field\\": \\"hello\\"}", "message": "Congratulations"}
```

Which is basically what I want except for all the extra `\\` characters.  Why are these being inserted into the json?  How can I modify my DjangoJSONEncoder so it doesn't insert the \ characters?

**NOTE**

If I just encode the model instance manually I don't get all the extra `\\` characters.

```
s = serialize('json', [t])
s[1:len(s)-2]
```

This outputs:

```
{"pk": null, "model": "hours.test", "fields": {"test_field": "hello"}
```

**EDIT**

Based on the advice of Daniel Roseman and Leopd I modified the DjangoJSONEncoder class to the following:

```
class DjangoJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
            # `default` must return a python serializable
            # structure, the easiest way is to load the JSON
            # string produced by `serialize` and return it
            return loads(serialize('python', obj))
        if isinstance(obj, models.Model):
            #do the same as above by making it a list first
            return serialize('python', [obj])[0]
        return JSONEncoder.default(self,obj)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your logic is wrong, unfortunately. Your "easiest way", as you state, returns a string - but you don't want a string at that point, you want a dictionary. You end up serializing a string within a string, hence the extra quotes which need to be escaped.

Luckily, one of the format options for the `serialize` function is `python` - which "serializes" the queryset to a Python dictionary. So you just need:

```
return serialize('python', obj))
```

Comment: Ah that helps a lot, and fixes an issue I probably would have had with querysets in the future, however, I'm currently working on the model case.  Using what you suggested I changed the code there to `return serialize('python', [obj])`, which works great except the entry field in the json is now a single element array.  Is there a simple way I could do this without making the model instance into a list first?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not without making it into a list, no - you probably just need `serialize('python', [obj])[0]`.

Comment: Ah so simple, just didn't see it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're serializing your `Test` model object into a JSON string, and then the `entry` field in `d` is the string, being serialized, not the data structure.