# How to properly convert a list of list into JSON in python?

Tags: python, json

I am still on python 2.7. I have a list of list in which I have some strings with double quotes. Below is what I have

```
new_row = [['<a href=/account_dtls/risks/edit/ACC-RISK-136053>ACC-RISK-136053</a>', 'Customer_152', 'External', 'Geographic / Diplomatic', u'Account', u'<span title=something "was" okay>something "was" okay</span>', 'gowri.subramanian', 'Open', 'saved', 'Client Location']]
```

I wish to convert it into a json. I follow the below steps in python interpreter in terminal

```
<type 'list'>
>>> json.dumps(new_row)
'[["<a href=/account_dtls/risks/edit/ACC-RISK-136053>ACC-RISK-136053</a>", "Customer_152", "External", "Geographic / Diplomatic", "Account", "<span title=something \\"was\\" okay>something \\"was\\" okay</span>", "gowri.subramanian", "Open", "saved", "Client Location"]]'
>>>
```

that gave me a neat json string with double quotes escaped. But my problem is I am running DJANGO and within it, I convert the same list of list into json and I get the below printed in my log file.

```
[["<a href=/account_dtls/risks/edit/ACC-RISK-136053>ACC-RISK-136053</a>", "Customer_152", "External", "Geographic / Diplomatic", "Account", "<span title=something \"was\" okay>something \"was\" okay</span>", "gowri.subramanian", "Open", "saved", "Client Location"]]
```

Notice that the double quotes around the word 'was' were not escaped with double backslashes and instead with single backslash. I pass this to front-end and I try to read it using JSON.parse() but it throws below error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'
```

When I checked it was like this

```
[[&quot;&lt;a href=/account_dtls/risks/edit/ACC-RISK-136053&gt;ACC-RISK-136053&lt;/a&gt;&quot;, &quot;Customer_152&quot;, &quot;External&quot;, &quot;Geographic / Diplomatic&quot;, &quot;Account&quot;, &quot;&lt;span title=something \&quot;was\&quot; okay&gt;something \&quot;was\&quot; okay&lt;/span&gt;&quot;, &quot;gowri.subramanian&quot;, &quot;Open&quot;, &quot;saved&quot;, &quot;Client Location&quot;]]
```

So I tried replacing the `&quot` with `"`

`replace(/&quot;/g,'"')`
But now I get the below error.
`VM86:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 164`

I am totally frustrated here. Can someone please help me what is going on here? and how shall I fix this?

Comment: take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064300/json-encoding-with-django-adding-extra-characters

Answer (score 0):

[`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) might help you as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14347168/7077066).

Comment: I followed your solution but it gives me ```ValueError: malformed string```error now.