# JSON serialize Django Queryset with values being called. Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Tags: python, django, json

Here is the problem: Django's serializer doesn't support dictionaries and simplejson doesn't support Django Querysets. See [JSON Serializing Django Models with simplejson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249792/json-serializing-django-models-with-simplejson)

I was wondering if there is anything wrong with my solution. I have something like:

```
people = People.objects.all().values('name', 'id')
json.dumps(list(people))
```

I am still a newbie with Python/Django. Is casting the `QuerySet` to a list a bad idea?  Is it more efficient to use the `DjangoJSONEncoder` suggested in the other topic?

Comment: Does this produce the desired output? What output would you like to get?

Comment: It works and has the desired output.  I was wondering if it is the best approach.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your solution is totally valid and very clean in my own opinion.

If you need a list of lists (instead of a list of dictionaries) you can use too:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

people = People.objects.all().values_list('name', 'id')
simplejson.dumps(list(people))
```

Sometimes when the json output is very complex we usually use a json template with the *render_to_string* function, for example:

```
context = {'people': People.objects.all().values('name', 'id')}
render_to_string('templates/people.json', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The template *people.json* could be:

```
[
 {% for person in people %}
    {"name": {{ person.name }}, "id": {{ person.id }} }
    {% if not forloop.last %} , {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
]
```

But the use of templates is reserved for more complex cases than yours. I think that for easier problems a good solution is to use simplejson.dumps function.

Comment: I would not recommend that anybody use this solution. As written, it will not work because it needs quotes, but even if you added quotes you would need to make sure the strings are escaped according to the JSON standard. No need to reinvent the JSON serializer if it's provided to you by your language.